# Probability of having less than 3 females if....

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

> Assuming that half the population is female and assuming that 100
>   samples of 10 individuals are taken, how many samples would you expect
>   to  have 3 or less females?

Can someone please explain how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed sample of $10$ individuals, assuming a large population, the probability $p_F$ of $3$ or less females is 
$$
  p_F
= \sum_{i=0}^3 \binom{10}{i} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}
= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}(1 + 10 + 45 + 120)
= \frac{176}{1024}.
$$
If you perform this experiment $100$ times you therefore expect to see fewer than $3$ females 
$$
        100p_F
=       \frac{17600}{1024}
\approx 17.1875
$$
times.

Comment: Explanation please :)

Comment: @Little Child Which part is unclear? The computation of $p_F$ comes from the fact that this is a binomial experiment. I assume this is okay since you yourself added the binomial theorem tag to the question. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a sample has $3$ or less females is $$p = \biggl(\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^{10} + 10 \cdot \biggl(\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^{10} + \binom{10}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^{10} + \binom{10}{3}\biggl(\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^{10}$$

Thus we have to calculate the expected value of a binomial random variable with the previous $p$ , i.e. $$N = 100 \cdot p$$

Comment: I think you left out the case of $0$ females

Comment: @user139388: I have edited

Comment: np ... I wouldn't want to live in a world with $0$ females either! :)

Comment: @user139388: true story

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be of any   help

[image: png]

Comment: You've reversed the order in the exponents of $0.5$: it should be $(0.5)^x(0.5)^{10-x}$. Also, you should be summing the expression. Finally, you got the wrong number.

Comment: you are right.I did not show the sum sign. the correct answer is 0.1718175*100=17.187